# Cannot Invert Matrix using Lapack DGETRF/DGETRI in VBA

Tags: vba, fortran, lapack, intel-mkl, matrix-inverse

I am trying to invert matrix in VBA Excel 32bit by using Lapack Fortran library [DGETRF](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/matrix-factorization-lapack-computational-routines/getrf.html?wapkw=getrf)/[DGETRI](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/matrix-inversion-lapack-computational-routines/getri.html?wapkw=getri) function from mkl_rt.dll, which placed in "compilers_and_libraries_2020.1.216\windows\redist\ia32_win\mkl" folder after installing mkl_2020.

1. The issue is the Excel always quietly quits when the call is made.
2. I have just used the default mkl_rt.dll after install the MKL 2020 on my machine.
3. I follow this link and put all the dll together, but it still does not work:

[Declaring BLAS functions from Intel MKL dll in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181563/declaring-blas-functions-from-intel-mkl-dll-in-vba-exce..).

4. I read some comments that I need to use STDCALL, however, I cannot find the method to use this function.

```
   Private Declare Function dgetrf Lib "*path\mkl_rt.dll" _
 (ByVal N As Integer, _
     ByVal M As Integer, _
     ByRef A As Double, _
     ByRef LDA As Integer, _
     ByRef IPIV As Integer, _
    ByRef INFO As Integer)

      
 Private Declare Function dgetri Lib "*path\mkl_rt.dll" _
    (ByVal N As Integer, _
    ByRef A As Double, _
    ByRef LDA As Integer, _
    ByRef IPIV As Integer, _
    ByRef WORK As Double, _
    ByRef LWORK As Integer, _
    ByRef INFO1 As Integer)
```

The using Subject

```
Public Sub NewMatrixSolver(ByVal Matrix1 As Matrix)

Dim M, N, LDA,  As Integer
Dim INFO,INFO1  As Integer
Dim A() As Double
Dim IPIV() As Integer

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'' copy value from matrix1 to A array
ReDim A(1 To MRows, 1 To MCols) As Double
For i = 1 To MRows
 For j = 1 To MCols
  A(i, j) = Matrix1.GetValue(i, j) '' in-house function - tested
 Next
Next

ReDim IPIV(1 To MRows) As Integer
For i = 1 To MRows
 IPIV(i) = 0
Next

''CALL recursive LU algorithm
M = MRows
N = MCols
LDA = MRows
INFO = 0

Call dgetrf(M, N, A(1, 1), LDA, IPIV(1), INFO)

If INFO <> 0 Then
 MsgBox ("Error: Unable to invert matrix.")
 Stop
End If

''CALL inverse of a matrix using the LU factorization
LWORK = MRows
INFO1 = 0
Call dgetri(N, A(1, 1), LDA, IPIV(1), WORK, LWORK, INFO1)

If INFO1 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox ("Error: Unable to invert matrix.")
 Stop
End If

'' Use inverted Matrix A

end sub
```

the using library
[dgetrf](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/matrix-factorization-lapack-computational-routines/getrf.html?wapkw=getrf)
[dgetri](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/matrix-inversion-lapack-computational-routines/getri.html?wapkw=getri)

Please let me know if you guys need more information.

Comment: The simplest is to write a Fortran (or C) function, declared STDCALL, which itself calls all the necessary routines in MKL. You **can't** call a function from VBA (32 bits) if it's not STDCALL. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions